# How to set default set of permissions for files in cpanel

Tags: linux, cpanel

When I upload / extract a file I get wrong permissions, I want 644 as default.

Im trying tog install Prestashop manually on a vps server With whm,  cpanel,  centos. I have tried with unmask 022, but it doesnt work for me.

Anyone how  to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have got root (super-user) access to the server then you can use this script: boomshadow.net/tech/fixes/fixperms-script/

This use 644 by default for files & 755 for folders. Or you can do it manually with chmod one by one of with find to do it in better way:

```
find /home/$Your_cPanel_Username/public_html/ -name '*.php' -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

This command will search for all PHP files under boomshadow.net/tech/fixes/fixperms-script/ & assign 644 permissions on those.

Comment: Is there any way to set the file and folder permissions when they are first created? Having to do this each time a new account is created via WHM isn't practical.